# Is there Linux kernel version limitation for virtual machines to run on GCE?

Tags: migration, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I migrated CentOS6.0 run on VirtualBox to GCE by using CloudEndure, but migrated VM could not be launched by following error:

```
SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-20171012_061934-google)
Total RAM Size = 0x00000003c0000000 = 15360 MiB
CPUs found: 4 Max CPUs supported: 4
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=266338304 = 130048 MiB
drive 0x000f2ff0: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=266338304
Booting from Hard Disk 0...
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Linux version 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b6.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri May 20 03:51:51 BST 2011
Command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us crashkernel=auto disable_mtrr_trim console=ttyS0 rd_NO_LVMCONF
KERNEL supported cpus:
Intel GenuineIntel
AMD AuthenticAMD
Centaur CentaurHauls
BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 (usable)
BIOS-e820: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bfffd000 (usable)
BIOS-e820: 00000000bfffd000 - 00000000c0000000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 0000000400000000 (usable)
DMI 2.4 present.
last_pfn = 0x400000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x70106, new 0x7010600070106
last_pfn = 0xbfffd max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Using GB pages for direct mapping
init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-00000000bfffd000
init_memory_mapping: 0000000100000000-0000000400000000
RAMDISK: 3735e000 - 37feff91
ACPI: RSDP 00000000000f3030 00014 (v00 Google)
ACPI: RSDT 00000000bfffdb90 00034 (v01 Google GOOGRSDT 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
ACPI: FACP 00000000bfffff00 000F4 (v02 Google GOOGFACP 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
ACPI: DSDT 00000000bfffdbd0 017B2 (v01 Google GOOGDSDT 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
ACPI: FACS 00000000bffffec0 00040
ACPI: SSDT 00000000bffff4c0 009F2 (v01 Google GOOGSSDT 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
ACPI: APIC 00000000bffff3c0 00086 (v01 Google GOOGAPIC 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
ACPI: WAET 00000000bffff390 00028 (v01 Google GOOGWAET 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
No NUMA configuration found
Faking a node at 0000000000000000-0000000400000000
Bootmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-0000000400000000
NODE_DATA [000000000000a000 - 000000000003dfff]
bootmap [0000000000100000 - 000000000017ffff] pages 80
(7 early reservations) ==> bootmem [0000000000 - 0400000000]
#0 [0000000000 - 0000001000] BIOS data page ==> [0000000000 - 0000001000]
#1 [0000006000 - 0000008000] TRAMPOLINE ==> [0000006000 - 0000008000]
#2 [0001000000 - 0001c9eff8] TEXT DATA BSS ==> [0001000000 - 0001c9eff8]
#3 [003735e000 - 0037feff91] RAMDISK ==> [003735e000 - 0037feff91]
#4 [000009fc00 - 0000100000] BIOS reserved ==> [000009fc00 - 0000100000]
#5 [0001c9f000 - 0001c9f0fd] BRK ==> [0001c9f000 - 0001c9f0fd]
#6 [0000008000 - 000000a000] PGTABLE ==> [0000008000 - 000000a000]
found SMP MP-table at [ffff8800000f32c0] f32c0
Reserving 129MB of memory at 32MB for crashkernel (System RAM: 16384MB)
kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:18bf901, boot clock
Zone PFN ranges:
DMA 0x00000001 -> 0x00001000
DMA32 0x00001000 -> 0x00100000
Normal 0x00100000 -> 0x00400000
Movable zone start PFN for each node
early_node_map[3] active PFN ranges
0: 0x00000001 -> 0x0000009f
0: 0x00000100 -> 0x000bfffd
0: 0x00100000 -> 0x00400000
ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0xb008
ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x00] lapic_id[0x00] enabled)
ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x02] lapic_id[0x02] enabled)
ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x01] lapic_id[0x01] enabled)
ACPI: LAPIC (acpi_id[0x03] lapic_id[0x03] enabled)
ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])
ACPI: IOAPIC (id[0x00] address[0xfec00000] gsi_base[0])
IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 0, version 17, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 5 global_irq 5 high level)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 10 global_irq 10 high level)
ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 11 global_irq 11 high level)
Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
SMP: Allowing 4 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
PM: Registered nosave memory: 000000000009f000 - 00000000000a0000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000a0000 - 00000000000f0000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000bfffd000 - 00000000c0000000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000c0000000 - 00000000fffbc000
PM: Registered nosave memory: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000
Allocating PCI resources starting at c0000000 (gap: c0000000:3ffbc000)
Booting paravirtualized kernel on KVM
NR_CPUS:4096 nr_cpumask_bits:4 nr_cpu_ids:4 nr_node_ids:1
PERCPU: Embedded 31 pages/cpu @ffff880028200000 s95064 r8192 d23720 u524288
pcpu-alloc: s95064 r8192 d23720 u524288 alloc=1*2097152
pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1 2 3
kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 0:28216901, primary cpu clock
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on. Total pages: 3874614
Policy zone: Normal
Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us crashkernel=129M@0M disable_mtrr_trim console=ttyS0 rd_NO_LVMCONF
PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
xsave/xrstor: enabled xstate_bv 0x7, cntxt size 0x340
Checking aperture...
No AGP bridge found
AMD-Vi disabled by default: pass amd_iommu=on to enable
PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
Placing 64MB software IO TLB between ffff880020000000 - ffff880024000000
software IO TLB at phys 0x20000000 - 0x24000000
Memory: 15288248k/16777216k available (4935k kernel code, 1048980k absent, 439988k reserved, 3927k data, 1220k init)
Hierarchical RCU implementation.
NR_IRQS:33024 nr_irqs:440
Console: colour *CGA 80x25
console [ttyS0] enabled
allocated 157286400 bytes of page_cgroup
please try 'cgroup_disable=memory' option if you don't want memory cgroups
Detected 2200.000 MHz processor.
Calibrating delay loop (skipped) preset value.. 4400.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=2200000)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Security Framework initialized
SELinux: Initializing.
Dentry cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 12, 16777216 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
Mount-cache hash table entries: 256
Initializing cgroup subsys ns
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
CPU: Physical Processor ID: 0
CPU: Processor Core ID: 0
mce: CPU supports 32 MCE banks
Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 79 no PMU driver, software events only.
alternatives: switching to unfair spinlock
ACPI: Core revision 20090903
ftrace: converting mcount calls to 0f 1f 44 00 00
ftrace: allocating 20276 entries in 80 pages
Enabling x2apic
Enabled x2apic
Setting APIC routing to physical x2apic
NMI watchdog: CPU not supported
..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=0 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
CPU0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz stepping 00
APIC timer registered as dummy, due to nmi_watchdog=1!
Booting Node 0, Processors #1
kvm-clock: cpu 1, msr 0:28296901, secondary cpu clock
#2
kvm-clock: cpu 2, msr 0:28316901, secondary cpu clock
#3 Ok.
kvm-clock: cpu 3, msr 0:28396901, secondary cpu clock
Brought up 4 CPUs
Total of 4 processors activated (17600.00 BogoMIPS).
Testing NMI watchdog ...
WARNING: CPU#0: NMI appears to be stuck (0->0)!
Please report this to bugzilla.kernel.org,
and attach the output of the 'dmesg' command.

WARNING: CPU#1: NMI appears to be stuck (0->0)!
Please report this to bugzilla.kernel.org,
and attach the output of the 'dmesg' command.

WARNING: CPU#2: NMI appears to be stuck (0->0)!
Please report this to bugzilla.kernel.org,
and attach the output of the 'dmesg' command.

WARNING: CPU#3: NMI appears to be stuck (0->0)!
Please report this to bugzilla.kernel.org,
and attach the output of the 'dmesg' command.
devtmpfs: initialized
regulator: core version 0.5
NET: Registered protocol family 16
ACPI: bus type pci registered
PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
ACPI: Executed 2 blocks of module-level executable AML code
ACPI: Interpreter enabled
ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
ACPI: No dock devices found.
ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (0000:00)
pci 0000:00:01.3: quirk: region b000-b03f claimed by PIIX4 ACPI
Unable to assume PCIe control: Disabling ASPM
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 5 *10 11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 5 10 *11)
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKS] (IRQs *9)
vgaarb: loaded
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
NetLabel: Initializing
NetLabel: domain hash size = 128
NetLabel: protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
NetLabel: unlabeled traffic allowed by default
Switching to clocksource kvm-clock
Clockevents: could not switch to one-shot mode:
Clockevents: could not switch to one-shot mode: lapic is not functional.
Could not switch to high resolution mode on CPU 0
Clockevents: could not switch to one-shot mode: lapic is not functional.
Could not switch to high resolution mode on CPU 2
Clockevents: could not switch to one-shot mode: lapic is not functional.
Could not switch to high resolution mode on CPU 3
lapic is not functional.
Could not switch to high resolution mode on CPU 1
pnp: PnP ACPI init
ACPI: bus type pnp registered
pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 524288 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 524288 bind 65536)
TCP reno registered
NET: Registered protocol family 1
pci 0000:00:00.0: Limiting direct PCI/PCI transfers
Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
Freeing initrd memory: 12871k freed
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(1513234620.373:1): initialized
HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
msgmni has been set to 29885
alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
ksign: Installing public key data
Loading keyring
- Added public key B5BD89AA2E85EC04
- User ID: Red Hat, Inc. (Kernel Module GPG key)
- Added public key D4A26C9CCD09BEDA
- User ID: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Driver Update Program <secalert@redhat.com>
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler anticipatory registered
io scheduler deadline registered
io scheduler cfq registered (default)
pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
pci-stub: invalid id string ""
input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
input: Sleep Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSLPBN:00/input/input1
ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPF]
processor LNXCPU:00: registered as cooling_device0
processor LNXCPU:01: registered as cooling_device1
processor LNXCPU:02: registered as cooling_device2
processor LNXCPU:03: registered as cooling_device3
Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
Linux agpgart interface v0.103
crash memory driver: version 1.0
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
�serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
Clockevents: could not switch to one-shot mode:
Clockevents: could not switch to one-shot mode: lapic is not functional.
Could not switch to high resolution mode on CPU 3
Clockevents: could not switch to one-shot mode: lapic is not functional.
Could not switch to high resolution mode on CPU 0
Clockevents: could not switch to one-shot mode: lapic is not functional.
Could not switch to high resolution mode on CPU 1
lapic is not functional.
Could not switch to high resolution mode on CPU 2
serial8250: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 6) is a 16550A
serial8250: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 7) is a 16550A
00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
00:05: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
00:06: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 6) is a 16550A
00:07: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 7) is a 16550A
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input2
Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBD,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
i8042.c: Warning: Keylock active.
serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4
rtc_cmos 00:01: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
rtc0: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
cpuidle: using governor ladder
cpuidle: using governor menu
usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver
TCP cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 17
registered taskstats version 1
IMA: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2017-12-14 06:57:02 UTC (1513234622)
Initalizing network drop monitor service
Freeing unused kernel memory: 1220k freed
Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 7176k
dracut: dracut-004-32.el6
device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
device-mapper: ioctl: 4.17.0-ioctl (2010-03-05) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
udev: starting version 147
dracut: Starting plymouth daemon
could not read byte from child: Success
putfont: PIO_FONT trying ...
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 11
virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKC] -> GSI 11 (level, high) -> IRQ 11
ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] enabled at IRQ 10
virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKD] -> GSI 10 (level, high) -> IRQ 10
input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
..input: ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
.................
setfont: putfont: 512,8x16: failed: -1
putfont: PIO_FONT: Invalid argument
No root devidracut Warning: LVM VolGroup/lv_root not found
ce found
dracut Warning: LVM VolGroup/lv_swap not found

Boot has failed, sleeping forever.
```

So, I asked the reason to CloudEndure support team, then the answer was as follows:

```
Kernel version 2.6.32-71 is too old to run on GCP.
Please install at least kernel 2.6.32-279+, reinstall the migration agent and try again.
```

Is there this limitation on GCE? And, is there Google official document which describes the limitation?
I browsed google documents, but I could not find out the documents.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this three links that can be usefull for you regarding your concerns:

1. [Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/migrating-vms-compute-engine#limitations)
2. [Building Custom Operating Systems](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/building-custom-os)
3. [Best practises when migrating](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-migrating-vm-to-compute-engine)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I've seen the links, but couldn't find the description about supported kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're running a 2.6.32-71 kernel.

Unfortunately, this kernel is too old and isn't supported by GCP.
For 2.6.32 RHEL/CentOS kernels, GCP only supports 2.6.32-279 or higher.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Yes, I used 2.6.32-71 kernel machine, and CloudEndure Support told me the supported version. but, I want to get the evidence from google official document or google support.